# Python fibonacci code error

Tags: python, runtime-error, fibonacci

I'm trying to write code that iteratively finds the nth fibonacci number. I've written my code below (using a bottom-up approach) but I get the following error. Can you please explain what the error is? Thanks.

```
def fib2(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    myarr = [None] * (n + 1)

    myarr[1] = 1
    myarr[2] = 1

    for index, element in enumerate(myarr[3:]):
        element = myarr[index - 1] + myarr[index - 2]

    return myarr[n]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    fib2(5)
  File "/Users/blah/Documents/myTest.py", line 16, in fib2
    element = myarr[index - 1] + myarr[index - 2]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Oh dear, you're adding nothing and nothing to create... nothing!

Comment: @Zizouz212 Could you let me know which lines of code are doing that? I thought I'm doing myArr[3] = 1 + 1, myArr[4] = 2 + 1 etc.

Comment: The answers are amazing by some of SO's favourite people. They'll make you understand it perfectly. :)

Comment: Why are you doing `myarr = [None] * (n + 1)`? This isn't C, you don't need to initialize arrays (called lists in Python) with empty values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate()` always starts counting at 0; it cannot know that you sliced your list:

```
for index, element in enumerate(myarr[3:]):
```

Here `index` starts at `0`, so you are trying to index *from the end* when you use `index - 1` and `index - 2`; these translate to `myarr[-1]` and `myarr[-2]`. Those entries are still set to `None`.

You are also not assigning values back to the list; rebinding `element` won't update the original list values.

You could give `enumerate()` a second argument to give a different starting value:

```
for index, element in enumerate(myarr[3:], 3):
    myarr[index] = myarr[index - 1] + myarr[index - 2]
```

or adjust your `index` calculations accordingly:

```
for index, element in enumerate(myarr[3:]):
    myarr[index + 3] = myarr[index + 2] + myarr[index + 1]
```

Note that now the `element` variable is no longer used. You could instead start your iteration from `myarr[2:]`:

```
for index, element in enumerate(myarr[2:]):
    myarr[index + 2] = myarr[index + 1] + element
```

Since you never need more than the last 2 values, the classical iterative Python implementation uses just 2 variables, not a list:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1

    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b

    return a
```

which uses Python's iterable assignment to great effect.

Comment: Why the special treatment for <=2?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: it can be removed; it just echoes the OP's function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, that was detailed and helpful! One thing I'd like to clarify is what you said about: "You are also not assigning values back to the list; rebinding element won't update the original list values." Can you explain why this is the case? I thought the scope rules in Python were local function, enclosing function locals, globals, and built in. So, since "element" is in a local function (fib2), why isn't the new value assigned to it?

Comment: @randomUser47534: assigning to `element` works just fine, but rebinding the name `element` is not the same thing as rebinding indices in `myarr`. The `for` loop receives values from the `enumerate()` function, which in turn draws values from `myarr`, and assigns those values to the `element` name. So in the loop body, `myarr[i]` and `element` both refer to the same integer object. Assigning a different integer to `element` then only alters what `element` refers to, `myarr[i]` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop doesn't actually modify the list. You have to modify the list itself instead of assigning to `element`:

```
for index in range(3, len(myarr)):
    myarr[index] = myarr[index - 1] + myarr[index - 2]
```

Also, since you need only the last two terms to compute the next term, you don't even need a list:

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1

    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b

    return a
```